# Cloud Firestore collection while offline returns empty

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I am testing the behavior of my React Native app offline. I am using Expo and a Cloud Firestore database. The code that I am using to update the screen is something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = db
  .collection('myCol1')
  .doc('myDoc1)
  .collection('myCol2')
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    // Update state based on snapshot.docs
    // But snapshot.docs is empty when offline
  });
return unsubscribe; }, []);
```

While online, everything is working great. Offline however, the collection that is fetched is empty. Is there something obvious that I am missing in terms of how caching works with Cloud Firestore? I am also not sure how to debug that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning on persistence:

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence();
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't persistence enabled by default for native apps? In any case I tried it with version 9.10.0 of Firebase but the problem persists.

Comment: It might be that offline is still not supported for the Firebase Web SDK on RN: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/436 and that I have to switch to `react-native-firebase`